# Query Optimization Mysql

Tags: mysql, optimization, sql-like

I am using this query for searching, but the query is slow. Can anyone suggest me an alternative for this query?

```
SELECT c.ctgr_name,n.lgcode,n.newsID,n.newsTITLE,n.image3,n.ctgr_code 
FROM tbnews  n LEFT JOIN tbcategory c ON c.ctgr_code=n.ctgr_code  
WHERE (newsTITLE LIKE "% Foray %" OR image3 LIKE "%Foray%" OR video3 LIKE "%Foray%" 
OR newsTITLE LIKE "% Foray %" OR image3 LIKE "%Foray%" OR video3 LIKE "%Foray%" ) 
AND (n.publish!=0) 
ORDER BY newsID DESC LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Always run EXPLAIN SELECT before asking for optimization. Stick "EXPLAIN" keyword before your query and then run it - MySQL will tell you what it wants to do and you'll see immediately where it gets stuck and where it doesn't use indexes.

2) Using LIKE '%%' searches (with percentage sign before AND after keyword) forces MySQL to do full table scan. Using a search such as LIKE 'keyword%' MIGHT make MySQL use the index on that field, if the index exists.

3) Configure your MySQL instance, tweaking the config and using appropriate storage engine can boost performance by a huge margin. By default, MySQL is configured to work on very slow machines and use very little resources - hence, when a table gets slightly larger (say, 100k rows), people notice performance drop. MySQL can cope with large tables easily, if configured properly.

Comment: can u tell me substitution of this query

Comment: Please read what I wrote, I think I explained everything in my post in clear English that anyone can understand. Without more info from your side - no, I can't help you further.

Comment: actualy i hosted a site with more than  500000 record in a table. the server adminsitration stop this site for only this above query. and i think that query is no such create this type of problem. i already used explain but i not found any problem.i used index on search fields.but i need an alternate query right now.

Comment: Did you post output of EXPLAIN here at SO for others to see?

Answer (score 0):

Using `LIKE "% Foray %"` constructions on a non-index field will slow the query down a lot. The more data you have, the more time it will take.

Consider adding some sort of keywords/tags mechanism with indexed field that you will search in. Probably an extra table.

Comment: i m using almost all fields for searching . may i index all those fields?

Answer (score 0):

Indexing probably won't help with  LIKE "%Foray%" type searches, as each string in the database needs to be scanned.

If you are searching for individual words, you can extract individual words into a seperate table which you can index effectively and reference them back to the original records. This will take more space, but will increase speed quite a bit.